# Are these css params or selectors correct?

Tags: css

I am working with a wordpress theme and my editor ( netbeans ) see a css file with some errors in it.

```css
.gallery-item{ max-width:50%); margin:0; }
```

I guess this could be a typo, but then comes these selectors:

```css
.footer-widget h3. { margin:10px 0; position:relative; }
.site-footer ., .site-footer . a, .site-footer .wp-caption-text {border-bottom:none; padding:0;}
```

The single dot is something that i'm not aware yet in css or it's just a mistake done by Author?

These are just a few examples with a single dot selector, more lines are found in the whole css file where the single dot selector is used and i'm not sure if it's something correct or needs to be fixed.

Comment: Pretty sure `.site-footer .` is not a valid CSS selector.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error at the ")" in this line:

```
.gallery-item{ max-width:50%); margin:0; }
```

It should not have the ")".

Also your "."(s) are wrong in this line:

```
.site-footer ., .site-footer . a,
```

I think maybe you are trying to do something like this:

```
.site-footer, .site-footer a,
```

Answer (score 0):

There are four errors in your/author's code. If you need to validate your code in future, you can use [**w3.org CSS Validator**](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator)

```
.gallery-item{ max-width:50%); margin:0; }
                            ^
                            |---- Remove the bracket


.footer-widget h3. { margin:10px 0; position:relative; }
                 ^
                 |---- Suffixed dot. It should be .h3

.site-footer ., 
             ^
             |---- Remove dot 

.site-footer . a,
              ^
              |---- Space after dot. Remove it
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-selectors-20051215/). More specifically, your editor is correctly identifying these as css errors. Just be sure that you are validating against the correct version of css.

Answer (score 0):

Original

```
.gallery-item{ max-width:50%`)`; margin:0; }
.footer-widget h3`.` { margin:10px 0; position:relative; }
.site-footer `.`, .site-footer `.` a, .site-footer .wp-caption-text {border-bottom:none; padding:0;}
```

Corrected

```
.gallery-item{ max-width:50%; margin:0; }
.footer-widget h3 { margin:10px 0; position:relative; }
.site-footer, .site-footer a, .site-footer .wp-caption-text {border-bottom:none; padding:0;}
```

if you've removed the containing element, with the mystery class (i.e. "."), then you shouldn't have a problem with the syntax-corrected rules. However, removing the classed selector from the middle may have undesirable results. We know that it existed previously due to remnant ".". without knowing what your markup looks like, I wouldn't know. A perhaps safer bet would be to target SOMETHING with a class even if that's vague. Obviously, it'd be better to appropriately select known elements, but something to try to target the correct elements would be replacing the periods with `[class!=""]`. this selects anything with a class.

More accurate:

```
.gallery-item{ max-width:50%; margin:0; }
.footer-widget h3 [class!=""] { margin:10px 0; position:relative; }
.site-footer [class!=""], .site-footer [class!=""] a, .site-footer .wp-caption-text {border-bottom:none; padding:0;}
```